# A function has at most one inverse.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

I only considered the case where $f$ is bijective, because if $f$ is not bijective, then $f$ doesn't have an inverse. (I can prove this statement also, I think).

Let $f: A \to B$ be a function and assume it has 2 different inverses (so $g_1\neq g_2$): $g_1$ and $g_2$ with $g_1: B \to A$ and $g_2: B \to A$.

Take an arbitrary $b \in B$. Because of what we assumed, it should follow that:
$(f\circ g_1)(b) \neq (f \circ g_2)(b)$.
$(f(g_1(b)) \neq f(g_2(b))$.
We already are confronted with a contradiction: because of the fact that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are functions, it follows that $g_1(b) = g_2(b)$ and thus $(f(g_1(b)) = f(g_2(b))$ . Because $b$ was arbitrarly chosen, we have given a proof that every bijective function has a unique inverse.
\qed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work.

1. The  fact that $g_1\neq g_2$ only  means that *there exists* a $b\in B$ such that $g_1(b)\neq g_2(b)$. Yet you take an *arbitrary* $b\in B$ and assume that this forces $(f\circ g_1)(b)\neq (f\circ g_2)(b)$ (presumably because $g_1(b)\neq g_2(b)$ and then invoking that $f$ is one-to-one). But there is *absolutely* no warrant to make that conclusion.
2. "because of the fact that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are functions, it follows that $g_1(b)=g_2(b)$." Sorry, but that is not accurate, either. You are assuming they are different functions; you don't know if they have the same (or different) values at any given $b$ juset from the fact that they are functions.
3. "because $b$ was arbitrarily chosen, we have given a proof that every bijective function has a unique inverse". This does not follow either. You were supposed to show that $g_1(b)=g_2(b)$ for all $b$ (so that $g_1=g_2$). You either never proved it, or else you assumed it.

There is no need to do a proof by contradiction. Remember that $h\colon B\to A$ is an inverse of $f$ if and only if $h\circ f = \mathrm{id}_A$ and $f\circ h=\mathrm{id}_B$.

Assume that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are both inverses of $f$. We want to show that $g_1=g_2$. Because they are both inverses, we have:
$$\begin{align*}
f\circ g_1 &= \mathrm{id}_B&\text{and}\quad g_1\circ f&=\mathrm{id}_A &\text{because }g_1\text{ is an inverse of }f\\
f\circ g_2 &= \mathrm{id}_B&\text{and}\quad g_2\circ f&=\mathrm{id}_A &\text{because }g_2\text{ is an inverse of }f
\end{align*}$$

Now also remember that if $h\colon X\to Y$ is any function, $\mathrm{id}_Y\circ h = h\circ \mathrm{id}_X = h$. So:
$$g_1 = g_1\circ\mathrm{id}_B = g_1\circ(f\circ g_2) = (g_1\circ f)\circ g_2 = \mathrm{id}_A\circ g_2 = g_2,$$
as desired.

Note a few features of this argument:

1. You don't need to prove that $f$ is bijective. This shows that any function has at most one inverse, since any two functions that are inverses must be the same.
2. It's a direct proof, not a proof by contradiction.
3. It actually proves more: we did not use that $g_1$ was an inverse on both sides and that $g_2$ was an inverse on both sides. In fact, we proved that if $h\circ f =\mathrm{id}_A$ and $f\circ g =\mathrm{id}_B$, then $h=g$ and they are the inverse of $f$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they're very useful. I wasn't thinking clearly enough while writing this proof and was not careful.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier than that. For $b\in B$ we have $$g_1(b)=g_1(f(g_2(b)))=(g_1(f))(g_2(b))=g_2(b)$$

Since this is true for all $b\in B$, $g_1=g_2$